# How to Grant access to the right directory dpending on username and password

Tags: apache, ubuntu, putty, digital-ocean

I will be using `example.com` for this question

my website like `dev.example.com` now i have 2 folders in `/var/www/dev.example.com/public_html`

`test1`

`test2`

now i want when someone visit my website `www.dev.example.com`, it will ask for the password. Depending on your username and password it will show you `www.dev.example.com/test1/index.html` if you enter the user and password for test1 directory

and depending on the username and password again it will take you to `www.dev.example.com/test2/index.html` directory

Lets say you have access to test1 and you log in the url should be

`www.dev.example.com/index` instead of `www.dev.example.com/test1/index.html`

I don't know if the normal .htaccess url rewrite will work for this kind of thing i am asking to be done.

How can I set this up? which files do i need to modifier in Apache or wherever for this to happen?

If you can show an example in your answer i will really apprentice it if not please point me to right files or location of files i need to add and a clue of what it is.